# ROS 2 Topic on different ROS DOMAINS

Tags: ros, python, ros2, communication, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I want to create a system where two robots are in different ROS_DOMAINS (one has ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1 and the other one has ROS_DOMAIN_ID=2 for example) and publish/subscribe to the same topic. Meaning that if Robot 1 publishes something to the topic, Robot 2 will be able to listen to it. Is this possible to do? And if so, how can I do it?

I am using ROS Eloquent with Python on Ubuntu 18.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351214/ros-2-topic-on-different-ros-domains/) by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-05-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MCornelis](https://answers.ros.org/users/44213/mcornelis/) on 2020-05-04**:
What is the reason for separating the robots by ROS_DOMAIN_ID? Is it not easier to just name_space the robots and have them in the same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The point of `ROS_DOMAIN_ID` is to isolate systems and prevent cross talk. If you want systems that will talk on some topics but not others you should use different namespaces and remap select topics to match.

There are ways to write a bridging node that is active on two ROS_DOMAIN_IDs but that's very technical and only recommended for very advanced users with very specific use cases.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1